# Does ksqldb 's custom udaf function guarantee concurrency(thread safe)?

Tags: concurrency, thread-safety, ksqldb

I'm running 5 ksqldb instance(k8s), and each instance thread(ksql server properties) num is 3

I implemented the udaf function to aggregate a simple map object using the udaf function. Data corruption did not occur when more than 10,000 pieces of data per minute were aggregated through the udaf function in a cluster environment.
My guess is that the udfa function seems to guarantee concurrency, am I right?

I have one more question
I am currently running a ksqldb instance in the k8s environment. Will the table aggregate data of ksqldb work normally without loss even in the restart situation?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, ksqlDB creates an new instance of called UDAFs and uses them in a single-threaded manner; ksqlDB does not re-use UDAFs.

This means that if you as an implementator write a UDAF which does not use global state, then, "yes", your UDAF should be thread-safe.

For your second question, I believe the answer is "yes".  UDAFs use the aggregate function to persist intermediate state to state stores; that ought to be restored when a ksqlDB node is restarted.

That said, technically, in either case, one could write a UDAF which fails to be thread-safe or does something really weird and would not restore properly.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
As you seem to be a Confluent's ksqldb developer, I would like to ask you a question about one thing!
I checked the ksql repo to check that the code is thread-safe. I checked the aggregate function part of the udaf function, but it doesn't seem to be any synchronization processing. Maybe I should check the other side?
(https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/a121a6abfa6add9630da0bc886fc7ad4f2d112f7/ksqldb-engine/src/main/java/io/confluent/ksql/function/UdafAggregateFunction.java#L63)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm following.  Are you asking if that method should be "synchronized"?  

Since there's an instance of a UDAF for each partition that's being processed, only a single thread would be calling that method for a given instance of the UDAF.  (I'm about 90% sure about that!:))